# How to get the minimum integer value of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a variable named `weight`that is a list full of int values. After each round of a loop I would like to either hide the current minimum value or replace it with a 'o' so that I may find the value that is the next least value.  `weight = [4,2,4,1,3,5,6,2,3]` for example would turn into `[4, 2, 4, 'o', 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]`.. The **problem** that I'm having is that when the loop makes it's second run it is producing an error because the addition of 'o'.

```
def greedyMinWt():
    weight = [4,2,4,1,3,5,6,2,3]
    value = [7,9,9,8,5,8,3,5,2]
    itemPick = [4,2,4,1,3,5,6,2,3]
    val = 0
    weightCount = 0
    itemCounter = 0
    valueCount = 0
    totalWeight = 0
    totalValue = 0
    weightInput = -1
    pickedItems = []
    n=0
    capacity = 17

    print('Itm|' + ' Wt|' + ' Val' )
    for num in range(0,len(weight)):
        print('(' + str(num+1) + ')' + '\t ' + str(weight[num]) + '\t ' + str(value[num]))
    print('\nSolve by greedy min wt:')
    while totalWeight < capacity:
         minWt = min(weight)
         val = value[weight.index(min(weight))]
         totalWeight += minWt
         totalValue += val
         slackWt = capacity - totalWeight
         'Need to fix this so it will print out the correct pick'

         if totalWeight > capacity:
            totalWeight-= min(weight)
            totalValue -=val
            print('\n__Greedy min weight __ \nItems Picked: '+ ' #' + ' #'.join(pickedItems))
            print('Feasible' + '\t' + 'WeightCount:' + str(totalWeight) + '\tValueCount:' + str(totalValue) + '\n' + 'The capacity is:' + str(capacity))
            return None
         print('pick =' + str(weight.index(minWt)+1) + ' accumWt=' + str(totalWeight) + ' slackWt=' + str(slackWt) + ' accumVal=' + str(totalValue))
         weight[weight.index(min(weight))] = 'o'
         print(weight)
```

Comment: If you want to find all the elements of the list in order from smallest to largest, why not just sort it?

Comment: Because I need it to be in a specific order and I'd like to accomplish it this way

Comment: @Crunch Hey again, see my answer below. Basically, I cast to strings to see if they are strictly numerical values.

Comment: ok, why are you so stuck on your current implementation? there are many better ways.

Comment: This is the way that my instructor wants it to be done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to extract the integers:

```
min_weight = min([i for i in weight if str(i).isdigit()])
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to know why I'm getting an error after replacing the min(weight) with 'o'

Answer (score 0):

This example loops through your `weight` list and extracts the minimum value. It puts this value into the `min_weights` list. The value that was found is then changed to `o`.

NOTE: If there are duplicate minimums, utilizing the `.index()` replaces the first minimum to `o`. The next time through the loop, the duplicate will be found, added to the other list and then changed to `o`

```
weight = [4,2,4,1,3,5,6,2,3]

min_weights = []
for x in range(len(weight)):
    min_weights.append(min(weight))
    weight[weight.index(min(weight))] = 'o'

print min_weights
print weight
```

This outputs the following:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]   # This is your minimum weights
['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']   # This is your weight list after the loop is complete
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Again. With the EXACT coding above how do I ensure that once I replace the current minimum value with 'o' that I won't get an error and will be able to continue finding the minimum values?